# Unable to pass value by pointer in a while loop

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

I understand that you can pass a value indirectly via a pointer: you specify that you assign the value (*) at some address (a pointer) to equal something (such as a char).

```
// This works: I can pass char indirectly via pointers    
// by saying "value at char pointer line equals c1 or c2"

char c1 = 'a';
char c2 = 'b';
char* line;

*line = c1;    
*(line+1) = c2;
```

And I can slide on memory space rightwards by using *(line+1) above.  However, when I loop it, this fails (below):

```
// Output: "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"    
// Why?   

char c;    
char* line1;    
int i = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    *(line1+i) = c;    
    i++;    
}
```

Output: "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Why does it fail to pass value indirectly via pointer when I try to iterate in a while loop?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Is this c++? put tags on your question accordingly

Answer (score 3):

1. You can't assign a value to line1 because you never initialize it.
2. You are accessing memory you shouldn't with line+i

Maybe you want something like this:

```
char c;

char array[100];   // Allocate space for 100 chars

char* line1 = array;    // Pointer to allocated memory block

int i = 0;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)

{

    *(line1+i) = c;

    i++;
    // Exit when i == 100
}
```

Comment: Agreed, I never initialized line1, but I also never initialized line in the top block of code and I am able to walk through the memory space using c1 and c2.  How is this different?

Comment: You are playing Russuan Roulette. In the first example, your compiler is not assigning a value to line1 so it gets some random value (use printf("0x%08X", line1) to test). In the first example, you are just getting lucky that writing to that location does not cause a page fault. However, your luck runs out in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign an address to line1, that is point it to somewhere or allocate a buffer that it points to.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not initialise line1 correctly then it can't work.

Try `char line1[500];` instead of `char* line1;` - for a test only; it still will crash if you enter more than 500 characters.

Comment: Thanks.  What if I do not know how much memory I need in advance while I am coding, and the size of the array will only be revealed during run-time?

Comment: By the way, in my example you should do `char line[500]; char *line1 = line`, as you could not modify the address of the array in the loop.

Comment: Up to your question: If you know at runtime how much space you need then you use `char line[] = (char *)malloc(500)` (or a variable instead of 500). If you never know how much space you need - for example if you can enter as many characters as you like - then it gets more difficult, because you have to handle in your program the case the loop goes over the last element of your buffer. You can `realloc()` the memory or you create linked lists or sth. else. Have a look into the literature.

Answer (score 0):

Line1 is not initialized with anything. The address it points at is undefined.

In C, (or C++), when you declare a variable as a pointer type, the variable isn't automatically assigned with an valid address.
Something like this.

```
DataType *a_certain_ptr;
```

What do you think a_certain_ptr contains? Another example might give you a cue.

```
int a_certain_number;    // this line is in some function.
```

What is the value of a_certain_number?

It shouldn't be hard to figure out that a_certain_number can be anything, it is uninitialized and thus its value undefined.
It can be equal to 1, -1, or 15033, etc.

Same applies to a_certain_ptr. This variable now, because you don't initialize it, can contain any value. It can be 1, -1, 353210, or maybe even an valid address pointing to somewhere on your stack...

So later on when you trying to execute

```
*(line1+i) = c;
```

you are referring to an invalid address offset'ed by **i*sizeof(char)** bytes, which is still invalid....

Comment: Thanks!  I'd +1 your answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do that yet...